# Javascript async / Promises, promise pending, now missing ) after argument list

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise, async-await

I keep getting Promise { pending } with the following stub of code:

```
const files = require('./controllers/search/files');
console.log(
    (async() => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            resolve(await files.getArray(PATH));
        });
    })()
);
```

Node.JS keeps saying that I am missing ) after resolve(, but I don't see what the issue is.
I am using Express.JS and Node.JS. I am trying to take the filenames from a directory and store them inside of an array for further use.

Comment: From what I see, there is an `async` missing for the `Promise()` callback. Also you don't wait for the outer IIFE to finish. You'd need another await there to immediately see the result.

Comment: The `async` should be moved to the `Promise` callback: `new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => { ... })`

Comment: Since `files.getArray(PATH)` is already returning a Promise, why does there need to be another one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Syntax error is because `await` is allowed only inside `async` functions, while `((resolve, reject) => { ... }` is regular function.

The problem is that `new Promise` is promise construction antipattern. It isn't needed because there's already existing promise (considering that `files.getArray(PATH)` returns a promise).

Another problem is that `async` is syntactic sugar for regular function that returns a promise. It's impossible to return a value from `async` IIFE and use it synchronously with `console.log`.

Since [top-level `await`s](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await) aren't supported yet, the code should be wrapped with `async` IIFE:

```
(async() => {
  console.log(await files.getArray(PATH));
})()
```